# How can I get offset relative to grandparent elements in HTML?

Tags: javascript, dom

If I have `<p> some text <b> some oth|er text </b> bla bla </p>` where the | is the caret and I want to get the offset relative to the p tag node, is there a way maybe I can find the offset relative to the p ?

Right now I am getting the offset of the selection by this:

```
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0); 
var offset = range.startOffset;
```

however this returns the offset relative to the bold tag.

I need this since I am developing an editor in Javascript and I need to implement the enter functionality myself since I am using this editor for real time collaboration. I found this problem when someone presses enter key in the middle of a child of the p tag.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably better ways to achieve this, but I haven't played enough with selections and ranges yet. However, I was thinking that since you already know the characters offset relative to the `b` tag, you would only have to add to the count the number of characters contained within text nodes that comes before the `b` tag to know the total offset.

I believe you could get the parent node of the `b` tag by doing something like, `range.startContainer.parentNode`.

Then, you could loop over the `childNodes` of the `p` tag until `childNodes[i]` is the `b` tag and each time you encounter a text node (`node.nodeType === 3`), you add `node.textContent.length` to the offset.